# No such column error when column does exist

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have three tables: nanoProd, nanoFiles, and nanoRelFiles. Third table is used to store the file meta and how they relate to other screens.

I'm getting an error that a column doesn't exist when I know it does and I'm not sure why:

```
no such column: nanoFiles.fileLoc: 
SELECT 
prodTable.name AS prodName,
prodTable.intro AS prodIntro,
prodTable.prodText AS nanoText,
nanoFiles.fileLoc AS nanoFile
FROM nanoProd AS prodTable
LEFT JOIN nanoRelFiles on nanoFiles.rid = nanoRelFiles.file_id
LEFT JOIN nanoProd ON nanoProd.rid = nanoRelFiles.item_id
WHERE nanoRelFiles.scr_type = 'prod' AND nanoRelFiles.fileUse = 'list'
```

Comment: You don't have `nanoFiles` in the `from` clause or either of the `join` clauses...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't joining to any table called "nanoFiles." You need to `JOIN` to that table to be able to `SELECT` from that column. Something like this:

```
FROM nanoProd AS prodTable
JOIN nanoFiles on ...
LEFT JOIN nanoRelFiles on nanoFiles.rid = nanoRelFiles.file_id
```